# add quotes around variable in ansible variables

Tags: postgresql, jinja2, ansible

I've got problem with one of ansible playbooks (enrise.postgresql).

It accepts variable postgresql_listen_addresses (list of values to listen_addresses in /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf).

I want to use value ansible_default_ipv4.address, but ansible provide it without quotes, and postgress wants it with single quotes (like '192.168.0.1').

I have variable like this:

```
postgresql_listen_addresses: '{{ [ ansible_default_ipv4.address ] }}'
```

When address is without quotes, postgress complains about unquoted IP address (syntax error).

How can I add quotes around value of ansible_default_ipv4.address?

Thanks.

UPD:

I was able to solve it with this ugly code. If someone can better, please help.

```
print_quotes: "'%s'"
postgresql_listen_addresses: [ "{{print_quotes|format(ansible_default_ipv4.address) }}"
```

Comment: Your solution, while ugly, worked for me after trying many things, thanks for posting! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `quote` filter:

```
postgresql_listen_addresses: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address | quote }}"
```

See [Playbooks Filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html).

Comment: The documentation of that filter states: "return its argument quoted for shell usage". So the quote filter decides, in my case it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try this?

```
postgresql_listen_addresses: "[ '{{ansible_default_ipv4.address}}' ]"
```

or this if postgress expects double quotes instead of single.

```
postgresql_listen_addresses: '[ "{{ansible_default_ipv4.address}}" ]'
```

I have no simple way of testing so I only have hope to support the theory... :-)